# How to specify or extend the CSS-class of a menu item?

Tags: menus

is there a way to allow admin users to add classes to individual menu items in the back end? we have done some individual javascripting and CSS using the title tag, but that is not flexible as it is visible to the end user, so the method is not suited effects needed to be applied to multiple items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is natively supported by WordPress. In the menus page, click "Screen Options" (in the upper right corner):

[image: Screen Options]

Then check "CSS Classes":

[image: Check CSS Classes]

You will now have a "CSS Classes" Option for each menu item:

[image: Enter CSS Classes]

Comment: Very nice. I never looked at the screen options for that page.

Comment: awesome, can we we set this problematically?

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: Take a look at the DB options table and set it to true on init (should be some autoloaded option).